# Ansible, creating a role to deploy an app on different machines with different versions and different configs

Tags: ansible

I need to install PHP on different machines, with different versions (7.1 and 7.4) and different configs, with Ansible.

I would like to use a single role, but with different vars files.

I would also like to use some parameters to deploy 7.1 or 7.4 and based on that param to deploy the correct version with the correct config. The configs do not differ by much (there are differences on files and folders locations).

Is there a way to do this from a single role?

Thank you!
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Override the variables with those stored in the `group_vars` or `host_vars` directories of your inventory.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable